# Wireless intermittently failing on 12.04 and 12.10

Tags: 12.04, wireless, connection

I seem to have a failing wireless card that happens after a few hours. This card is new and works fine in a windows 7 pc (I installed it to make sure it works).

My machine is as follows:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:08:54:a2:73:86
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192se driverversion=3.5.0-23-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.1.63 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe500000-fe503fff

uname -a
Linux core 3.5.0-23-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 13:15:40 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Device 8892 (rev 30)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)

/sbin/ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:54:a2:73:86  
          inet addr:10.0.1.63  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::208:54ff:fea2:7386/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2021 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1762 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2060458 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:295268 (295.2 KB)
```

When the issues happens I see NO errors in /var/log/syslog, except that when I attempt to reconnect to the wifi AP, it just keeps deauthing / never correctly authing. Even if I remove the saved AP and re-enter it, it fails. I also tried restarting the network-manager, that doesn't help.

I also make sure the card isn't entering power-save mode, that's turned :off.

If I reboot the machine, the wifi will work for a few more hour(s), and then fail.

Any help - this is a deal breaker for me currently. =[

UPDATE:
When this happens, wlan0 still reports and IP, though I cannot ping anything on my network, nor my gateway x.x.x.1.

The card in question is: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833166063

Comment: I filed a bug for this issue because it's happening despite changing to a USB wifi card.